# Micronaut: Race condition in MicronautTest when initializing jdbc connection

Tags: kotlin, micronaut

Since upgrading from Micronaut 1.3.2 to 1.3.4 our unit tests that involve the jdbc layer fail randomly with the error:

> io.micronaut.transaction.exceptions.NoTransactionException: No current transaction present. Consider declaring @Transactional on the surrounding method

It fails approximately 50% of the time

The exception happens in this code block

```
@PostConstruct
@Transactional
private fun init() {
    liquibase = Liquibase(
        "db/liquibase-changelog.xml",
        ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(),
        JdbcConnection(dataSource.getConnection())
    )
}
```

in this class

```
@Singleton
open class TestUtils {
    @Inject
    @field:Client("/")
    lateinit var client: HttpClient
    @Inject
    lateinit var objectMapper: ObjectMapper
    @field:Property(name = "micronaut.application.name")
    lateinit var applicationName: String
    @field:Property(name = "micronaut.application.version")
    lateinit var applicationVersion: String
    @field:Property(name = "testing.security.access-token")
    lateinit var accessToken: String

    @Inject
    lateinit var dataSource: DataSource

    private var liquibase: Liquibase? = null

    @PostConstruct
    @Transactional
    private fun init() {
        liquibase = Liquibase(
            "db/liquibase-changelog.xml",
            ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(),
            JdbcConnection(dataSource.getConnection())
        )
    }

    fun tearDownDatabase(){
        liquibase?.dropAll()
    }

    fun setUpDatabase(){
        liquibase?.update("")
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want the `@PostConstruct` method to be transactional?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I figured it had to be there, since Liquibase executes some inserts, but anyway that's not the problem, the behaviour stays the same, with or without it

Comment: Your calls to manipulate the database need a transaction, not the init method.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a solution, had to move the initializing of liquibase to it's own method:

```
    @PostConstruct
    private fun init() {
        initLiquibase()
    }

    @Transactional
    private fun initLiquibase() {
        liquibase = Liquibase(
            "db/liquibase-changelog.xml",
            ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(),
            JdbcConnection(dataSource.getConnection())
        )
    }
```

Now it seems to work 100% of the time again